# What is the DC of Symbol Of Persuasion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In the spells description it only says Will negates but i can't find it's DC's.

Comment: Who's casting the spell and what's his key ability score for his spellcasting?

Comment: Related: [What is spell DC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26190/what-is-spell-dc)

Comment: Similar answer, but this is a more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All spells follow a similar formula to calculate the DC of a [saving throw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Saving-Throw):

> **Saving Throw Difficulty Class**
>
> A saving throw against your spell has a **DC of 10 + the level of the spell + your bonus for the relevant ability** (Intelligence for a wizard, Charisma for a bard, paladin, or sorcerer, or Wisdom for a cleric, druid, or ranger). A spell’s level can vary depending on your class. Always use the spell level applicable to your class.

You can find the spell level in the first line after the name of a spell:

> School enchantment (charm) [mind-affecting]; **Level cleric/oracle 6, sorcerer/wizard 6, witch 6**; Subdomain revolution 6, tyranny 6

[Symbol of Persuasion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/symbol-of-persuasion/) is a 6th level spell for all classes that can normally cast it, so the DC is the same for all of them:

- cleric: DC 16 + wisdom modifier;
- wizard/witch: DC 16 + intelligence modifier;
- sorcerer/oracle: DC 16 + charisma modifier.